# DataDog Monitor alert notification to Distribution lists NOT received

Tags: alert, monitor, datadog, distribution-list

I have created a DataDog Monitor. Set the alert notification to be sent to some Distribution lists and some separate mails. Separate mails receive the notification, while the mails in distribution list are not receiving the notification. If it is set to teams id it is working. Is this a bug of DataDog or any other format to be used with Distribution lists?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the distribution list server is rejecting the email for some reason. I'm guessing all the distro lists are part of the same organization? If you can, speak with the admin of those lists and see if they are blocking certain types of emails, and see if they can add Datadog to the grantlist.

For more information about the errors, you can use the [events explorer](https://docs.datadoghq.com/events/explorer/) to search for events with the string `Error delivering notification`. If you don't see any errors correlating to the missing emails, you can be pretty sure they are being delivered but are being held by the receiving server.